# How do I get WWW::Mechanize to properly handle 302 redirects with URI fragments?

Tags: perl, mechanize, http-redirect, lwp

I have a webpage which redirects to another url in the form of http://www.example.com/url.html#midpage.

I'm wondering if there's anyway for [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize) to follow http://www.example.com/url.html instead of http://www.example.com/url.html#midpage?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where's your short demonstration script that shows the problem? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I think you mean 302 redirects.

Answer (score 1):

[`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) subclasses [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm), so you can still use any of `LWP::UserAgent`'s methods. Thus you can use the `simple_request()` method, which doesn't automatically handle redirects. It just returns you the response as an [`HTTP::Resonse`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/HTTP/Response.pm) object. Which means you can use the `is_redirect()` and `header()` methods to get the redirect URI. Which means you can then use the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module to pull off everything after the #.

Whew!

Your code would look something like this:

```
my $response = $mech->simple_request( HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.example.com/') );
if( $response->is_redirect ) {
  my $location = $response->header( "Location" );
  my $uri = new URI( $location );
  my $new_url = $uri->scheme . $uri->opaque;
# And here is where you do the load of the new URL.
}
```

There may be some twiddling to do, potentially around the `header()` line, but this would be the general idea.

Comment: I think I might have just unset the fragment portion, but it's basically the same approach. You'd do the same thing in a reponse_done handler.

Answer (score 1):

[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) is a subclass of [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl), so the answer is the same.

If you want to handle the redirect yourself to rewrite URLs, you might want to use a `response_done` or `response_redirect` handler. See the "Handlers" section of the LWP::UserAgent docs.

As for "properly", the [HTTP specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) doesn't say what a client should do with a fragment except in 14.6 in the case of a referrer header (and that's the only place the word "fragment" even shows up).